# How can I style a local html file through browser extensions like Tampermonkey or Dark Reader?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I always use Dark Reader or my own Tampermonkey script to view websites in Dark mode on the internet. But Both don't work on the local HTML files created by third parties like software manuals.  How can I style them as using Dark Reader or Tampermonkey script? Or other methods on local files?

Comment: Go to details of that extension on chrome://extensions page and enable file access toggle.

Comment: Thanks!  This works!!